# AJAX URL getting accessed before click() occurs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am building an ASP.NET Web Application. To parse the form data and get the result, I used AJAX and jQuery. I want the action to execute only after I click `#btnPrint`. `StoreinDB` is responsible for storing the passed data into the SQL Database table. However the `StoreinDB()` method in the controller executes as soon as the page loads. This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnPrint').click(function() {
    console.log("Button Clicked")
    if ($("#txtsomething").val().length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("StoreInDB", "Controller")',
        data: {
          a: "10232",
          b: qty,
          c: $("#txtsomething2").val(),
          d: $("#txtsomething3").val(),
          e: sum
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response) {}
      });
    }
  });
});
```

There is a `console.log` in the code and `Button Clicked` appears in the console only after the button is clicked. Which means the event isn't firing unless the button is clicked. Then, I added a breakpoint at `url: @Url.Action()` method in the AJAX block. As soon as the page loads, the breakpoint is hit. Without clicking the button. What is going wrong? And how can I implement the StoreinDB method?

Comment: The code in the question is fine, and there is nothing there which will trigger the button click on load. There must be something else in your logic which is causing that behaviour.

Comment: If I remove the `@Url.Action()` method, the breakpoint does not hit. Is there any replacement for @Url.Action()? Maybe it is an inherent property of C# itself. As soon as it sees familiar syntax, it executes.

Comment: The `@Url.Action()` is output from the server side logic and not in any way relevant to the client-side.

Comment: So, how can I access the controller method? Any method will do.

Comment: I also just noticed you already asked this exact question an hour ago. Please do not duplicate your own questions. If you did not receive an answer please edit the original to include more pertinent information.

Comment: The code you have shown above is the correct way. The point here is that you have an underlying problem which is not detailed above. You need to debug your logic to determine where it's coming from

Comment: Ok, I'll try and see. Thanks! My apologies